# Is there a reason to use MSE over R^2 for scaled data?

Tags: regression, r-squared, mse

It seems that in the case of a scaled dependent variable (mean subtracted, divided by SD), the relationship between R^2 and MSE becomes:

R^2 = 1 - MSE

(http://brenocon.com/rsquared_is_mse_rescaled.pdf)

Typically, R^2 is subject to many pitfalls in assessing model performance, and thus a loss metric like MSE is preferred.

However, in this case they appear to be directly related. As such, is there really any "benefit" to using MSE in this instance?

Comment: $R^2$ does not have the usual “percent of variability explained” interpretation when the model is nonlinear.

Comment: Right -- but in this case, it doesn't seem like MSE is giving me any more information / is more valid, given that MSE=1-R^2 for scaled data (variance = 1), no? I'm just trying to get confirmation as to whether these measures are interchangeable in the specific case of scaled data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have answered your own question.

> is there really any "benefit" to using $MSE$ in this instance?

If

$ R^2 = 1 - MSE $

..for a particular model, then it is obvious that their is no benefit in using one over the other.

Comment: Does this answer your question ? If so, please consider marking it as the accepted answer, or if not please let us know why so that it can be improved.